# MVC logout all active sessions after same user login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, logout

I have c# mvc web application.There is simple login page according to email and password. Now I have a need like that:
When a user login to the system, all active sessions that same email address will logout.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Session.Abandon()` or `Clear()` to abandon the current session, but if there are  multiple people logged in with the same address, this will not address that.

You'd have to build that detection in; for instance, you could update a flag on the table that represents your users and then in the other user's sessions periodically check the table if they were re-logged in.  OR when a user logs in, create a token in a database table with an expiration date; associate that token to a user in a cookie.  When logged out or logging back in, you could invalidate the token associated to that email address, and each user, when they attempt to access the application, could be rejected by your application checking whether the token is expired.

Answer (score 1):

The `Abandon` method should work ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28VS.90%29.aspx)):

```
Session.Abandon();
```

If you want to remove a specific item from the session use ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.remove.aspx)):

```
Session.Remove("YourItem");
```

If you just want to clear a value you can do:

```
Session["YourItem"] = null;
```

If you want to clear all keys do:

```
Session.Clear();
```

If none of these are working for you then something fishy is going on.  I would check to see where you are assigning the value and verify that it is not getting reassigned after you clear the value.

Simple check do:

```
Session["YourKey"] = "Test";  // creates the key
Session.Remove("YourKey");    // removes the key
bool gone = (Session["YourKey"] == null);   // tests that the remove worked
```